# Help me decode a word: coptchat? cotchrat?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request, phonetics

A man in a documentary [Beyond good and evil](https://youtu.be/1CSuJUWJRwg?t=277) says:

> Noone could fulfill that task and without suggesting crudely or simplistically that he coptrchat into madness, I do think that some such escape was inevitable.

What is this coptrchat?

Comment: This is discoverable in 10 seconds on Google: "that he copped out by retreating into madness".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transcription should read

> No one could fulfill that task and without suggesting crudely or simplistically that he **copped out** by retreating into madness, I do think that some such escape was inevitable.

> [to cop out](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cop%20out)
>
> to shirk responsibility

The speaker is saying Nietzsche was avoiding responsibility by escaping into madness.